# How to append new fabric.Canvas to existing canvas element? new fabric.Canvas is replacing existing canvas element

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am wanting to use fabric.js freeDraw. I want to append or add the fabric.Canvas on top of an existing canvas element that also has interactivity. However, when I use new fabric.Canvas it is replacing the existing canvas.

My existing canvas looks like this in the body:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="2160" height="1440" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
```

I am trying to add the new fabric.Canvas on top by saying:

```
var canvasDraw = new fabric.Canvas('canvasDraw', { width:500, height:500, isDrawingMode: true});
```

So in short, I want to be able to freeDraw on the existing canvas by using fabric.js however that is possible. Either by inserting the new fabric.Canvas on top of the existing one or however it should be done.

Thank you,
Eric